# Is $d(x,y)=|x-y|^2$ a distance on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Please how to prove that $d(x,y)=|x-y|^2$ is a distance on $\mathbb{R}$, I don't know how to solve the triangular inequality.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: in $\mathbb{R}$, $|x-y|^2 = (x-y)^2$.

Comment: for points $0, 0.5, 1$ we have $|0 - 0.5|^2 + |0.5 - 1|^2 = 0.5 < 1 = |0 - 1|^2$. So $d(x, y)$ does not obey triangle inequality and is not a metric then.

Comment: why -2 ? if there are personne who don't know the answer so why -2 ?

Comment: Proof: $$d(x,y)=(x-y)^2$$
$$(x-y-z+z)^2$$
$$(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2+2*(x-y)*(x-z)$$$$d(x,z)+d(y,z)+ 2*(x-y)*(x-z)$$The last term can be both positive or negative. So, it is not a metric space.

Answer (score 9):

It's not true. Consider $x=0$, $y=1$, $z=2$. Then
$$4 = d(x,z) \not\leq d(x,y) + d(y,z) = 1 + 1 = 2$$